# Checking duplicate in an array that contains objects as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if there exists duplicate `outputTypeId` in the `output` array object..

Below is the JSON:

```
 $scope.entities=  [
        {
            "input": {
                "id": 134
            },
            "output": [
                {
                    "id": 135,
                    "outputTypeId": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "input": {
                "id": 134
            },
            "output": [
                {
                    "id": 135,
                    "outputTypeId": 7
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "input": {
                "id": 134
            },
            "output": [
                {
                    "id": 135,
                    "outputTypeId": 9
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Below is the code that I tried but its not going inside the condition after execution..

Let `outputTypeId` be [7] as I'm checking for multiple outputTypeId's,hence an array

```
   $scope.checkForDuplicateOutputs = (outputTypeId) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.entities.length; i++) {
            for (var j = i; j < $scope.entities[i].output[j].length; j++) {

                if (outputTypeId.contains($scope.entities[i].output[j].outputTypeId)) {
                    $scope.isDuplicateOutput = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    $scope.isDuplicateOutput = false;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function checkForDuplicates(outputTypeIds) {
       $scope.isDuplicateOutput = $scope.entities.some(function(entity) { // Loop through entities
           return entity.output.some(function(entityOutput) { // Look for any output
              return outputTypeIds.indexOf(entityOutput.outputTypeId) != -1; // which is duplicated in 'outputTypeIds'
           });
       });
    }
```

So this solution uses `Array.some` - It has a few advantages:

- Removes the need to manually `break` your loops
- No need to have `i` and `j` variables to keep track of loop counters
- No need to duplicate `$scope.isDuplicateOutput = <boolean>;`
- Less lines of code :)

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking only the inner loop with that `break` statement and the problem is even though the duplicate flag does get set to true, it will be reset to false in the next iteration. Basically, in the end you'll get the result of the last iteration only.

The quickest fix is to use a flag to denote whether the external loop needs to be stopped:

```
$scope.checkForDuplicateOutputs = (outputTypeId) => {
    var breakOut = false;                 // <--- this is new
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.entities.length; i++) {
        if (breakOut) break;              // <--- this is new
        for (var j = i; j < $scope.entities[i].output[j].length; j++) 
            if (outputTypeId.contains($scope.entities[i].output[j].outputTypeId)) {
                $scope.isDuplicateOutput = true;
                breakOut = true;          // <--- this is new
                break;
            } else {
                $scope.isDuplicateOutput = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you still want to iterate all the entities and have a list of all the duplicates, you can make `$scope.isDuplicateOutput` an array and just push the duplicate ids into it.